# Gson: How to change specific fields key from serialization

Tags: java, gson, pojo

I am using Gson for serialization and I'm struggling with changing field names dynamically. Here is my class:

```java
public class Response<T> 
{

    private String status;
    private String message;
    private T data;

    public Response(T data) 
    {
        this.setData(data);
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }     

}
```

I have to change the field names dynamically based on the resource. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Using maps may be not the best choice since your `Response` class may have special Gson annotations that will be ignored once your response objects are converted to maps.

Suppose the following simple response class:

```java
final class Response<T> {

    @Expose(serialize = true)
    final String status = "STATUS";

    @Expose(serialize = true)
    final String message = "MESSAGE";

    @Expose(serialize = true)
    final T data;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    final String whatever = "WHATEVER";

    Response(final T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

This response does not use another Gson annotations for simplicity. Ad hoc use of a dynamic field renaming:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
        // ... any Gson configuration here ...
        .create();
final Response<List<String>> response = new Response<>(ImmutableList.of("foo", "bar"));
final JsonElement jsonTree = gson.toJsonTree(response, stringListResponseTypeToken.getType());
final JsonObject responseJson = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();
final JsonElement dataPropertyJson = responseJson.get("data");
responseJson.remove("data");
responseJson.add(response.getClass().getSimpleName(), dataPropertyJson);
gson.toJson(responseJson, System.out);
```

Note that the main trick here is creating an intermediate JSON tree and substituting the dynamic property name. Unfortunately, this solution requires an intermediate JSON tree. Another, more "Gson-ish" solution is creating a special type adapter in order not to re-map the response objects everytime it's necessary.

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
        // ... any Gson configuration here ...
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getDynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
final Response<List<String>> response = new Response<>(ImmutableList.of("foo", "bar"));
gson.toJson(response, stringListResponseTypeToken.getType(), System.out);
```

Where the type adapter factory and type adapters are implemented as follows:

```java
final class DynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory dynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory = new DynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory();

    private DynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getDynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return dynamicPropertyResponseTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( Response.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<Response<Object>> delegateTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<Response<Object>>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) getDynamicPropertyResponseJsonTypeAdapter(delegateTypeAdapter, gson);
            return castTypeAdapter;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Note that this type adapter factory picks the downstream type adapter to avoid infinite recursion if the handled class is `Response`, and otherwise `null` is returned to let Gson use its own (de)serialization strategies.

```java
final class DynamicPropertyResponseJsonTypeAdapter<T>
        extends TypeAdapter<Response<T>> {

    private final TypeAdapter<Response<T>> delegateTypeAdapter;
    private final Gson gson;

    private DynamicPropertyResponseJsonTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<Response<T>> delegateTypeAdapter, final Gson gson) {
        this.delegateTypeAdapter = delegateTypeAdapter;
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    static <T> TypeAdapter<Response<T>> getDynamicPropertyResponseJsonTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<Response<T>> delegateTypeAdapter, final Gson gson) {
        return new DynamicPropertyResponseJsonTypeAdapter<>(delegateTypeAdapter, gson);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Response<T> response)
            throws IOException {
        if ( response == null ) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        final JsonElement jsonTree = delegateTypeAdapter.toJsonTree(response);
        final JsonObject responseJson = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();
        final JsonElement dataPropertyJson = responseJson.get("data");
        responseJson.remove("data");
        responseJson.add(response.getClass().getSimpleName(), dataPropertyJson);
        gson.toJson(responseJson, out);
    }

    @Override
    public Response<T> read(final JsonReader in) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

The same not very cheap trick is used above, but now it works as a part of the `Gson` instance. For both cases the output is as follows:

> {"status":"STATUS","message":"MESSAGE","Response":["foo","bar"]}

Another options you might want to take into account are:

- Making the `Response` class abstract and letting the child classes to define their own `data` field names via `@SerializedName` if the names are supposed to be hard-coded.
- Creating your implementation `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` (see the Gson source code) and making the fields names dynamic without creating an intemediate JSON trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the field's name than it means you don't need type safety, so the following will do:

```
Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
response.put("message", message);
response.put("status", status);
response.put(dynamicFieldName, dynamicFieldValue);
String json = gson.toJson(response);
```

You can still wrap a convenience library on top of this low-level code to account for common use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HashMap for such cases?

```
private HashMap<String, String> data;

public HashMap<String, String> getData() {
    return this.data;
}

public void setDataValue(String key, String value) {
    data.put(key, value);
}
```

Note that the data field can be a HashMap of `<String, Object>` or `<Long, Object>` too, to save sub-objects, thus accepting all kind of Gson supported structures.